# Locator.geocode(...) freezes/blocks UI in OS 5 devices(Blackberry Java)

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me

In my BlackBerry app, the `Locator.geocode(...)` request is inside a `Thread` but it still blocks the UI in OS 5 devices. In OS 6 and 7 devices it works fine. The UI is not blocked.

From the moment `Locator.geocode(...)` is called till it finishes the UI is blocked and user can't interact with the application.

I guess this is a OS 5 issue. Is there a solution for this?

---

**Update:** First of all, thanks for quick replies.

1. I replaced `Locator.geocode(...)` call for `Thread.sleep(...)`. The UI gets slowed down but not blocked. The simulator I'm using is 9300.
2. The `Locator.geocode(...)` request is inside a `try..catch()` block and it throws no Exceptions. After the call finishes it returns `null` (I'm using simulator) but no exception are being thrown.

For your information, this is what the console prints: (Using 9300 simulator)

> ****** Number of threads before creating Geocode class: 4
>
> ****** Number of threads inside Geocode class just before calling Locator.geocode: 5
>
> ****** Running on event thread: false
>
> Locator.geocode(...) // UI blocks at this point(OS 5) till this
>   request finishes

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have it running on a thread properly? It may be that OS 6+ is just responding faster, so you only notice the problem on OS 5.  Try replacing the call to `Locator.geocode()` with a call to `Thread.sleep(60000)` to make sure the background thread is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Locator` documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/Locator.html):

> *Requests for geocode information are synchronous, but can be interrupted by invoking cancel(). An application can use the Locator class to make only one request at a time. Making more than one request results in a MapServiceException. *

So thats one thing to check in your code. Make sure you don't make multiple request. Another possible problem:

> *If the LBS Map API is not installed on a BlackBerry device, requests for geocode information will throw a MapServiceException.*

In both cases, an exception being thrown in a thread will terminate that thread, but this wont affect other threads like the event thread. So, without reading the code, I'd say your problem is not related to locator. It will be really helpful if you pasted some code or an exception trace.